Local costamp not cleared properly
Summary:
I am using a TOF depth camera to convert the received point cloud into a laser scan and add it to the costmap. However, when the dynamic obstacles (i.e. people) move out of the camera's FOV, the global costmap clears the obstacles and updates correctly, but the local cost map does not.
Global + Local costmap:

Global costmap only:

Details:
Information in the laser scan message:

range_min = 0.01
range_max = 3.0
The out of range points are set to inf

Costmap settings:
costmap_common_params.yaml
max_obstacle_height: 0.4
robot_radius: 0.3
map_type: costmap

tof_layer:
  enabled:              true
  footprint_clearing_enabled:  true
  max_obstacle_height:  0.4
  z_voxels:             2
  origin_z:             0.0
  z_resolution:         0.2
  unknown_threshold:    15
  mark_threshold:       0
  combination_method:   1
  publish_voxel_map:    false
  track_unknown_space:  true
  observation_sources:  tof_center_scan
  
  tof_center_scan:
    data_type: LaserScan
    topic: /tof_center_scan
    inf_is_valid: true
    marking: true
    clearing: true
    min_obstacle_height: 0.0
    max_obstacle_height: 0.4
    obstacle_range :     2.5
    raytrace_range :     5.0

global_costmap_params.yaml
global_costmap:
  robot_radius: 0.3
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  static_map: true
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: tof_layer,               type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

local_costmap_params.yaml
local_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 10.0
   publish_frequency: 10.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 5
   height: 5
   resolution: 0.05
   transform_tolerance: 0.5
   plugins:
    - {name: tof_layer,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,     type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

Some reference say that costmap_2d may failed to clear obstacles sometimes due to limitations of the Bresenham2D algorithm, but I am confused why the obstacles are cleared in the global costmap but not in the local costmap.
